# Testing Symfony 2 form that contains html data

Tags: html, forms, symfony, web-crawler, richtext

Given that a page http://test.intra has the following form code:

```
<form>
<textarea id="description" name="description">&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit_save" id='submit_btn' value="Save">
</form>
```

`description field` is submitted on browser with value `&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt`;

**But using the following code:**

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://test.intra');     
/* $client is a instance of \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client ] 
 * $crawler is a instance of \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler
*/

$domForm = $crawler->filter('form');
$domForm = $domForm->selectButton('submit_btn');
$this->client->submit($form);
```

`description field` is submited with value `&amp;lt;p&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;`

Should client [`\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client`] decode form data before submit is called? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are asking, but I noticed your code wasn't correct.

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://test.intra');

$domForm = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
$crawler = $this->client->submit($domForm);
```

Now you'll be able to check your asserts on $crawler.

```
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```